# Запись в файл Java

Tags: java

Проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь записать полученное значение поля, выводится 0 вместо нужного.

Выводит - 0.0
Должно (Сумма может меняться) - 7500.0
Так как у меня есть метод `getBalanc` который работает

```java
protected void checkBalanc() {  // Проверка баланса
    System.out.println("\n" + "Hei " + getNAME_CARD() 
        + " " + getSURNAME_CARD() + " your balanc = " 
        + getBalanc() + "EUR");
    Check.printCheckBalanc();
}
```

Но когда я пытаюсь записать это в файл, всё выходит кроме `getBalanc`.

```java
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(check)) { // check имя файла для записи
    pw.println("Check #1 - " + functional.getNAME_CARD() + " " 
        + functional.getSURNAME_CARD());
    pw.println(functional.getBalanc());
    pw.println(sdf.format(date));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Выводит данное сообщение в текст

```
Check #1 - Anton Voloxin
0.0
20-01-2023
```

Доказательство, что работает `Balanc = 7500.0EUR` вывод в консоль

```java
System.out.println("\n" + "Balanc = " + getBalanc() + "EUR");
```

Comment: нужен воспроизводимый пример. по огрызку кода угадывать причину проблемы - так себе идея

Comment: Вероятно, какие-то упомянутые методы вызываются для разных экземпляров, имеющих разные данные.  Информации о проблеме  слишком мало.

Comment: https://github.com/Svartov/ATM добавил в гитхаб

Comment: @DavidTepols Чтобы идти на гитхаб и изучать там код, нужно относительно много энтузиазма. У людей, которые могли бы вам ответить, с большой вероятностью может не оказаться столько -- у них обычно есть свои дела, достаточно важные и срочные. А вот если вы прочитаете пару мест и будете следовать изложенным там рекомендациям, то ваши шансы получить полезный ответ вырастут в разы или в десятки раз. Вот эти места: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example К тому же, если вы это выполните, вы сами наверняка сможете найти причину

Comment: Я написал часть кода, они сказали что слишком мало информации, учитывая что у меня 4 класса и всех их сюда отправлять не лучшая идея, по этому я загрузил на гит, чтобы всё 4 класса не вставлять сюда

Comment: Как и ожидалось, в классе `Check` вы создаётё новый экземпляр `Functional` и печатаете его содержимое внутри метода `printCheckBalance`, вместо того, чтобы передать ссылку на "рабочий" экземпляр в упомянутый статический метод `/* Functional::checkBalance */ Check.printCheckBalance(this);`  В целом, ваш вопрос показывает неумение воспользоваться инструментами отладки, и не представляет особой ценности.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, благодаря вам я вспомнил что учил и как нельзя делать)

Answer (score -1):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что ваша переменная balanc закреплена не за классом Functional, а за объектом.

```java
    private double balanc; // значение по умолчанию 0
```

И при каждом создании нового объекта класса Functional создаётся новая переменная `balanc`. Вам стоит закрепить переменную за классом, иначе говоря сделать её статичной.

```java
    private static double balanc; // значение по умолчанию 0
```

Исправьте если не прав

Comment: Вы смотрели код автора вопроса на гитхабе? :)  Ваше "решение" позволяет автору получить желаемый результат, но совет использовать "статический" баланс вместо корректной работы с полями и экземплярами не слишком удачен.